# OpenLayers 6: I can't remove ImageLayer

Tags: openlayers

What is the difference between adding an ImageLayer like this:

```
new ImageLayer({
    map: map,
});
```

And this:

```
map.addLayer(imageLayer);
```

I'm asking because I can't remove the layer if I pass the map to the ImageLayer in the properties.

```
map.removeLayer(imageLayer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unmanaged layers are not added to the layer collection, so to remove them you would need to use

```
imageLayer.setMap(null);
```

See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_VectorImage-VectorImageLayer.html#setMap

Comment: Thanks, Mike, I just tried to call the dispose function, and it works also. imageLayer.dispose(). Does it make any difference to your suggestion?